# Conversion error in CreateThread

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I have a weird bug when I try to use the `CreateThread` function. Here's my code:

```
HANDLE threads[3];  //threads[0] is printer, threads[1] is receiver, [2] is serverconn
    DWORD  printer_id,  receiver_id, serverconn_id;
    if(
                      ((threads [0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, printer_thread,    (LPVOID) thread_args, 0, &printer_id)) == NULL) ||
        ((recv_thread = threads [1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, receiver_thread,   (LPVOID) thread_args, 0, &receiver_id)) == NULL) ||
                      ((threads [2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, serverconn_thread, (LPVOID) thread_args, 0, &serverconn_id)) == NULL)
    )
    {
        IO_print_line("Initialization error");
        return FALSE;
    }
```

`printer_thread`, `receiver_thread` and `serverconn_thread` are functions defined like this:

`int serverconn_thread(LPVOID args);`

The Visual Studio compiler gives me this error:

```
Error   C2440   'function': cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(LPVOID)' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
```

And I really don't get it since I think I've done exactly [what the official documentation suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx).

And no, changing the thread functions' return type to `DWORD` doesn't solve anything, the error only changes to:

```
Error   C2440   'function': cannot convert from 'DWORD (__cdecl *)(LPVOID)' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
```

Weird thing is if I change it like this:

```
if(
                      ((threads [0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &printer_thread,    (LPVOID) thread_args, 0, &printer_id)) == NULL) ||
        ((recv_thread = threads [1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &receiver_thread,   (LPVOID) thread_args, 0, &receiver_id)) == NULL) ||
                      ((threads [2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &serverconn_thread, (LPVOID) thread_args, 0, &serverconn_id)) == NULL)
    )
```

With a forced cast, compiler is ok but I don't think it's a good idea to brute-force it this way. How do I fix this?

Comment: Then why does the official Microsoft example go with `DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction( LPVOID lpParam )`?

Comment: @EärendilBaggins `WINAPI` is just a macro for `__stdcall`

Comment: the `WINAPI` is macro expanded to `__stdcall`. also you can use `CALLBACK` macro here. all this the same

Comment: Isn't putting `WINAPI` after stuff deprecated? When I used `HANDLE WINAPI` I got a warning from the compiler

Comment: It worked anyway, so I guess it was that. I just would like to understand what exactly the `__stdcall` is and why it's considered an archaism (or whatever the compiler defined it) if put after `HANDLE`

Comment: because __stdcall is calling convention. have sense only for functions. when you declare `HANDLE WINAPI h;` - this is really anachronism

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT following the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736.aspx) when declaring your thread functions.

Your original declarations were using `int` as the return value, and `__cdecl` (implicitly) as the calling convention.  When you changed the return value to `DWORD`, you did not change the calling convention.

However, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736.aspx) clearly shows the correct declaration:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  _In_ LPVOID lpParameter
);
```

`DWORD` is an `unsigned long`, and `WINAPI` is a macro that maps to the `__stdcall` calling convention (see [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)).

So, the correct declaration of your functions would be:

```
unsigned long __stdcall printer_thread(void *args);
unsigned long __stdcall receiver_thread(void *args);
unsigned long __stdcall serverconn_thread(void *args);
```

However, since `CreateThread()` takes an `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` as input, which is declared as `DWORD (WINAPI*)(LPVOID)` (see the actual declaration in `winbase.h`), you should declare your functions to match:

```
DWORD WINAPI printer_thread(LPVOID args);
DWORD WINAPI receiver_thread(LPVOID args);
DWORD WINAPI serverconn_thread(LPVOID args);
```

Comment: Is the `DWORD` really necessary? Cause `int __stdcall` was fine for the compiler, I wonder if it's actually any different as I don't really use the return value for the thread functions.

Comment: @EärendilBaggins: yes, `DWORD` is really necessary. `int` and `unsigned long` are different data types. If you use `int`, you have to use a typecast to pass your functions to `CreateThread`, and you shouldn't be using a typecast at all. If you have to resort to a typecast to please the compiler, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Guess I'm changing it to DWORD then. Don't want to typecast to a smaller type.

Comment: @EärendilBaggins: unless your compiler implements `long` as 64bit on Windows (most use 32bit, but some use 64bit), then `DWORD` and `int` will usually be the same size, but not the same signness. C and C++ are strongly typed languages. You have to use proper types.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ are strongly typed programming languages. They are statically typed, though, so the compiler can issue diagnostics for incompatible types.